# Scrapy help to get data from bad table

Tags: python, scrapy

My question is related to get data from bad table, i'm doing a lot of try without any result >.< maybe someone has a brilliant idea to parse a piece of s.. table.

What i need to acomplish:

- Login to the web page. [ DONE ]
- Get the data from every item of that table and make one file for item with that data. [ UNDONE ( except the file making thing that will be easy ) ]

Table structure example:

```
<tr class='divider'> # nonsense </tr>
<tr class='header'> # here's the name of the future file
 <td> # nonsense </td>
 <td class='title'>
  <div class='titlebox'> # really ...
   <span>
    <strong> THE TITLE </strong> # That's a data to be scraped
   </span>
  </div>
 </td>
 <td> # nonsense </td>
</tr>
<tr class='item_data'> # Here's the content of the output file
 <td> # nonsense </td>
 <td class='justanumber'> # Data needed
  1234
 </td>
 <td> # Here's a td without class but i need to get the data too
  blahblahblah
 </td>
 <td> # Here's the same as before
  123 blahblah
 </td>
 <td> # The same with a number
  1234
 </td>
 <td class='nonsense'> # nonsense </td>
</tr>
<tr class='useless'> # Just useless data </tr>
<tr class='divider'> # And after that will be the next item </tr>
```

It's getting incredible annoying get the item data because there's no wrapper for item, i need some ideas. I'll put the scrapy code example updated:

faktable.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy,urlparse
from Faktable.items import FaktableItem
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.http import Response
class FaktableSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "faktable"
    allowed_domains = ["faktable.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://faktable.com/login',
    )
    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formdata={'user':'name','pass':'thepass'},
            callback=self.after_login)]
    def after_login(self, response):
        faktable_name = response.xpath('//div[@class=""]').extract()
        for item in items:
            yield
```

Expected output:

```
Title_data;td_data(the first 1234);td_data(the blahblah);td_data(the 123 blah);td_data(the second 1234);
Title_data;td_data(the first 1234);td_data(the blahblah);td_data(the 123 blah);td_data(the second 1234);
Title_data;td_data(the first 1234);td_data(the blahblah);td_data(the 123 blah);td_data(the second 1234);
Title_data;td_data(the first 1234);td_data(the blahblah);td_data(the 123 blah);td_data(the second 1234);
Title_data;td_data(the first 1234);td_data(the blahblah);td_data(the 123 blah);td_data(the second 1234);
```

Comment: Can you please show us an expected output?

Comment: edited, sry forgot about that >.< Thanks !

Comment: Also a link to the actual page would be welcome, so I can see the real data in context.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not able to put the web coz it's a backend get data and i can't give the access ( that's why the scraper has the login function ) >.<.
But the structure of the shit table it's like the description ( yes, there're td with class and another without class or id ... ).